# UTC time 1 Hour Early Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an issue where time gets saved 1 hour early:

```
:time => "6:00AM".to_time
```

This saves as `"13:00 UTC"` when it should be `"14:00 UTC"`

I've set local time to PST:

```
config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
```

## Current solution:

Based on @hd1's explanation:

```
if Time.zone.now.dst?
    :time => "6:00AM".to_time + 1.hour
else
    :time => "6:00AM".to_time
end
```

Please let me know if there's a more direct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It almost looks like you're running into a daylight savings time issue. The Rails time extensions let you determine your current offset like Time.zone.now.utc_offset, and Time#dst? tells you if it's Daylight Savings Time with those two you can conditionally subtract the extra hour (3600 hundred seconds). Hope that helps. If it doesn't leave a comment and I'd be happy to dig into the rails source code for a solution.

Comment: Thanks - how would I use the offset to save the time correctly (updated code above). Should I add an if statement and manually subtract the hour?

Comment: Here's what I ended up doing (please let me know if this is correct): `if Time.zone.now.dst?` If currently DST, then `+ 1.hour`. Otherwise don't add 1 hour.